# Merge nodes with different labels into new node with both labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J database with a bunch of `employee` and `consultant` nodes, with a relationship `consults` pointing from a consultant to an employee node. A consultant can consult many employees and an employee can have multiple consultants.

My issue is that some (not all!) of the consultants are employees as well. How do I go about merging nodes to have two labels to specify those consultants that are employees?

I exported my data from Postgres and imported it to Neo so I have a bunch of nodes like the examples below:

The `name` field on all the nodes is unique.
Is there a way to match nodes with the same name, create a new node with the new title, and delete the old nodes?

`(c:Consultant {name:“Consultant1”})
(e:Employee {name:“Consultant1"})`

Desired fix:

`(p:Consultant:Employee {name:“Consultant1”)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APOC procedure [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#merge-nodes) should work for your use case.

It merges multiple nodes from a list into the first node, and also merges all their relationships as well.